# Best way to store list of string pairs for optimal query performance

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

Right now I use Dictionary to store some configuration data in my app. The data gets added to Dictionary only once but it gets very frequent queries. Dictionary has around 2500 items, all "keys" are unique.

So right now I have something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> Data;

public string GetValue(string key) // This gets hit very often
{
    string value;

        if (this.Data.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }

    ...
}
```

Is there more optimal way to do this?

Comment: That is a very fast way as it will not iterate thru the entire list but just try to access a key directly and return the result or null

Comment: @Devha, what do you mean in 'best way'? the fast one? the developer convenience?

Comment: @user3165438 best way = fastest way, in this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TryGetValue` is a pretty optimal way of returning an item so there's not much you can improve on that front. However, if this isn't causing a bottleneck at the moment, I wouldn't worry too much about trying to optimize `TryGetValue`.

One thing that you can do, but isn't shown in your code so I don't know if you are, is to create a `Dictionary` object with an estimated capacity. Since you seem to know the rough number of items that will be expected, creating the Dictionary with that capacity will improve performance as it would reduce the number of times .NET has to resize the dictionary.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4.aspx):

> If the size of the collection can be estimated, specifying the initial
>   capacity eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing
>   operations while adding elements to the Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks keyboardP. Adding items is not bottle new right now as the Dictionaty is populated only once in app life cycle. Im just wondering is there better collection than Dictionary, which are better for query intensive cases?

Comment: I think `Dictionary` looks like a good structure to use here, so if you're really having performance issues with lookups, you may want to either use multiple dictionaries of a lightweight database (although I'd be surprised if 2500 items is causing an issue but I guess that would depend on the type of project you're working on).

Answer (score 2):

What you have is pretty efficient. The only way to improve performance that I can think of is to use `int` as the dictionary key, instead of `string`. You would need to run performance tests to see how much it makes a difference in your use case -- it may or may not be significant.

And I would use an enum for storing the settings for convenience. Of course, this assumes you have a known set of settings.

```
private Dictionary<int, string> Data;

public string GetValue(MyAppSettingsEnum key) 
{
    string value;

    if (this.Data.TryGetValue((int)key, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that I don't use the enum directly as the dictionary key, as it is more efficient to use an `int` as the key. More details on that issue [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3885/dictionary-enum-t-puzzler).

Answer (score 1):

The only faster way is using an array if your keys are int and have a short range.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Using an array is a more optimal way to what op asked if some constraints are met.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the source code of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` (available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs) the most frequent code used in your case is

```cs
private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
    if( key == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }

    if (buckets != null) {
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

as you can see further the lookup is fast if the `comparer.GetHashCode` is fast and produces nice hash code distribution, if possible a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

The dictionary construction code is not visible in your example, but if you use the default constructor then the dictionary will use the default comparer `EqualityComparer<string>.Default`.

Providing your own comparer with time & space efficient hash function might speed up the code.

If you don't know how a good hash function should look like in your case, then using interned strings may also give you some boost (see http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-intern (or [MSDN: String.Intern Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx)))